# How to play videos on Apache server

Tags: apache, video-streaming, mp4

I have installed Apache server on a Ubuntu machine, created directory in Apache

/var/www/html/myvideos/

and copied the videos to this location, how do you play it back on the browser?

I have opened the URL in browser

http://my_server_ip/myvideos/testvideo.mp4

The video doesn't get played in the browser.
Do I need to make any configuration in Apache server to make the video play in the browser ?

Please guys, help me on this. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should embed a link to the video in your index.html by doing this.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
<source src="/var/www/html/myvideos/[videoname].mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Then, you can click the player in your `index.html`, and watch your video there.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution, I have tried it, but couldn't achieve.

Do I need to make any configuration in Apache to play MP4 files ?

Comment: No, you shouldn't need to. Last time I tried, it worked just fine.