# Playing VLC on a Ubuntu machine running an Apache server, no playback

Tags: linux, apache, perl, cgi, vlc

I've used xampp (lampp) to run an Apache2 server out of my Intel ComputeStick with Ubuntu 18.04.1 installed. I've written a .cgi script with perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI;

print CGI::header();

system("vlc /home/jack/Desktop/ayni1.mp4");
```

However, when I hop onto my laptop (Win10) and use Chrome to visit http://12.345.678.90:80/dashboard/perl/ayni1.cgi (That's my server, and that directory does exist), **nothing happens on the hosting machine.** In the browser, this line is displayed:

```
VLC media player 3.0.3 Vetinari Command Line Interface initialized. Type `help' for help. > Shutting down.
```

I'm afraid I don't quite understand what's happening. I thought cgi scripts interacted directly with the command line; i.e. they could issue commands to *Terminal* directly. Was I mistaken in that? What am I doing wrong?

Sorry, I know this question is somewhat scattered. If needed, I'll try to provide clarification as best I can.

I'm somewhat new to all of this.

Comment: `CGI::header()` won't cut it to serve an audio/video file. The output of `CGI::header()` is something like

   `Content-type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1`

which is not an appropriate header for video.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48648070/how-to-play-videos-on-apache-server, http://swimminginthought.com/streaming-mp4-video-webserver-solved/

Comment: I just realized I didn't clarify this in my post - I need to click a link on a computer on the network and the *hosting machine* will natively play a video on loop. Preferably through VLC.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have set VLC to open a command line interface automatically.

Reset the VLC preferences and it should work normally again.